# rrdtool: Display 2 values with correct size on y-axis

Tags: rrdtool

I want to display 2 values on the Y axis correctly with rrdtool.
The first value has a range of 0-70, the second from 0-800.

The scale of values should be appropriate. With --right-axis=0.1:0 I can adjust the naming on the right side, but the value is not "resized'd", so that e.g. a value "10" practically disappears on the 0 line when the 2nd value is 500.

Can this be done correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The option you want is `--right-axis 10:0` to display a second Y-axis that is scaled 10:1 with no offset.  You then need to scale your second variable before you plot it so that it will be relative to the second axis.

Here is an example

```
rrdtool graph --right-axis 10:0 \
  --vertical-label "Variable A" \
  --right-axis-label "Variable B" \
  DEF:a=file.rrd:a:MAX \
  DEF:b=file.rrd:b:MAX \
  CDEF:bb=b,10,/ \
  LINE:a#ff0000:VariableA \
  LINE:bb#00ff00:VariableB
```

Of course, if you want to print values for 'b' in the legend, then calculate them based on 'b' rather than 'bb'.

See here for the documentation: https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdgraph.en.html